# 米田さんによると、その可能性は高いものの、Ｈ５普通コンドライトは地球でもっとも多く見つかる隕石で、八王子隕石が偶然曽根隕石と同じ種類だった可能性もあるということです

Tags: grammar

> 米田さんによると、その可能性は**高いものの**、Ｈ５普通コンドライトは地球で**もっとも多く**見つかる隕石で、八王子隕石が偶然曽根隕石と同じ種類だった可能性もあるということです。 ([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0202.html?utm_int=news_contents_news-closeup_002))

My attempt at translation:

> According to Mr. Yoneda (?), Concerning the possibilities, out of the meteorites which are discovered more abundantly on earth (??? H5 ordinary chondrite of expensive things???), there is also the possibility that hachioji meteorite is similar to the Sone meteorite type.

I am profoundly puzzled by the parts in bold. Furthermore, I'm having a really hard time parsing the その可能性は**高いものの**、Ｈ５普通コンドライトは地球で**もっとも多く**見つかる隕石で part. First, there are two は and while I know both the topic marker and contrastive function, I'm lacking the creativity and skill to meaningfully resolve their functions in this sentence. I chose the のなかで interpretation for で in 見つかる隕石で because I find a way to translate it otherwise. I also have no idea what 高いものの、Ｈ５普通コンドライト is supposed to tell me, so tried to make the best out of it.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could try to come up with more descriptive titles for your questions.  When people try to find questions about ものの and so forth, they might search but won't be able to see anything useful from "Please help me with this sentence", which could describe literally half the questions on the site.

Comment: And could you please stop using that "concerning" unconditionally in your translation attempt? It almost always makes your translation unnatural, and we cannot judge if you have *understood* the sentence correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ものの is a disjunctive. It means “but” or “however.” For whatever reason, Japanese is very rich in disjunctives!

So you’re looking at two separate clauses, and that’s why you find two はs.

もっとも (sometimes written in kanji as 最も) is a more formal way of saying 一番. So もっとも多く見つかる means “most commonly found.”

The で following this clause is simply the copula in て form.

Does this get you all the way to the translation?

Comment: "According to Mr. Yaneda, Although this chance is high, H5 chondrite being the most commonly found meteorite on earth, there was also the chance that hachioji meteorite was by chance the same type as Sone meteorite."
This is what I would come up with following your explanation^^

Besides, I dont understand what exactly they are saying about these meteorites in the bigger context xD So hachioji is either H5 chondrite or Sone type? And Sone type and H5chondrite are very similar in their composition? Im still a bit confused by the articles contents alone ^^

Comment: I haven’t read the article, I’m afraid, just the sentence you provided. I believe the scientist is saying that the two fragments could be part of the same event, but they’re both a common type of meteorite so we can’t say for sure. So yes, I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: Also, I think he’s saying that both the Sone meteorite and the Hachiōji are H5 type.